# Is there a way to "alias" one class in Java for another?

Tags: java

I have the following API compatibility problem and looking for the ways to solve it.

**TL;DR Is there a way to create an "alias" for a class in Java? I.e. some trick to make `com.acme.foo.SomeEnum` to be an alias for `com.acme.bar.SomeEnum`?**

Long story. (I'm anonimizing it a bit to avoid fingerpointing.)

I'm working with a powerful Java tool which also supports plugins. There's no strictly defined *public* API (in a sense of what you can and can't touch), just usual private/protected/package/public classes, methods and fields. There are defined extension points (like, extend `com.acme.plugin.Plugin` class), but then you'll have access to a wide area of the tool's internals.

In the recent minor version update (like, `1.2.3` -> `1.2.4`) tool developers have moved one enum class to another package - `com.acme.foo.SomeEnum` became `com.acme.bar.SomeEnum`. I think it was thought just as a trivial refactoring, not as a serios restructuring.

This class, however, seems to have been used by a number of plugins. The result is that these plugins are now incompatible with the latest version. Most of the plugins are quite useful, but not actively maintained. People wrote them years ago - and they just worked over the years, with dozens of the version updates. So this has a potential of negative implact on the tool's plugin ecosystem.

---

My question is, if there's some way in Java to create an "alias" `com.acme.foo.SomeEnum` for `com.acme.bar.SomeEnum`? This would allow old plugins to continute working with the new version of the tool.

Some classloader trick? In JavaScript that would've been trivial to shim, but in Java?

Why *I* am asking this. I'm an author of the Maven plugin which wraps the tool in question. So I could easily add my sugar to this coffee, like classloaders and so on. If there is a technical way to make this work, I'd be in position to save most of the tool's plugins ecosystem - at least for Maven users.

I've contacted the tool's vendor on this, but not sure of the success.

Just to make it clear - *I* am *not* the vendor of The Tool in question. I (a) write plugins for The Tools (and have no big trouble updating *my* plugins) and (b) am an author of the `the-tool-maven-plugin` which allows execution The Tool in the Maven builds. I also consult a lot on The Tool and care about its ecosystem (there are a lot of very useful plugins).

---

**Update**

End of story: developers of The Tool took my points into account, and decided to revert the change. Kudos for that!

Comment: TL;DR - No there isn't.

Comment: (Except perhaps by using some of the debug facilities.)

Comment: Is this a compile time thing you want or a runtime one (as in reflection)?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Tool's plugins were compiled against (old) tool's JARs. I want to make these plugins executable with the new tool's JARs.

Comment: @HotLicks That would be unfortunate.

Comment: Stupid idea: can you define a `com.acme.foo` package in your code, create `SomeEnum` in that package, and see if the rest of the ecosystem keeps working? I have never tested anything like this, I wonder if this could work.

Comment: @Laf No, this won't work. Tool's interfaces will still use `bar.SomeEnum` so other plugins can't call The Tool with my `foo.SomeEnum` class.

Comment: There's a little-used [Proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class that should do what you need. Prof Kabutz has covered them a [couple](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue005.html) of [times](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue181.html).

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Hm, this static proxy thing looks very promising. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @lexicore - Because Prof Kabutz has it all there.

Comment: This is why it's important to ensure strong API design before the first release. ["*1.1.11: Do not move **or rename** the package of an already released public API*"](http://theamiableapi.com/java-cl-section-1-1/#cl.item.1.1.11). Your best choice would be to repackage ask @EJK mentioned. Although it's not pretty, what you're doing is frowned upon, so I suggest choosing the shiner of 2 poos (unless you dont mind keeping the original and just not refactoring it)

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I've read it through. Nice idea, but I don't think it will work for me. I don't need an instance of `bar.SomeEnum` based on `foo.SomeEnum`, I need `foo.SomeEnum` to be the same as `bar.SomeEnum`.... Maybe in combination with a classloader somehow...

Comment: @VinceEmigh That's surely very true. But the situation is now as it is. Not exactly clear, what's public and what's not (that enum is "public" in a sense of Java access modifier, by the way). An the class was moved. And that new version is already released. And that's a huge vendor.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, other applications using your API are importing that package/class in hard code. The only way to ensure their code won't break is to ensure they can still import it. ClassLoaders won't help you, seeing how the package must physically exist publicly in order to import. This is why it's important to design API with scalability in mind from the start. There were 2 wrong moves made: renaming the package, then releasing before checking if it'll break legacy code. There's no way around this, unless you implement a system that changes the client's bytecode somehow

Comment: @VinceEmigh Just to make it clear - I am not the vendor, this is not *my* API in that sense. I'm trying to persuade the vendor to revert that change and investigating technical options in parallel. So far what EJK suggested is the most feasible thing.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Hm, wait. But as a Maven plugin author for The Tool I *could* manipulate the bytecode of all the Tool's plugins that my Maven plugin loads. This seems to be another option.

Comment: @lexicore - ok so have you considered hacking the ClassLoader - just a thought - no idea how but that seems to be all you have left.

Comment: Even with the bytecode trick, applications (even apps made after the new release) will be forced to perform the check unless you can work by version somehow. It's an extremely sloppy fix, but changing a package name for a released API is a pretty sloppy mistake. The vendor should know not to do such things, and the blame goes on the dev team. The right fix would be to get everyone you know to contact the vendor, and make them aware of this petty mistake. Other than that, check out [bytecode manipulation](http://www.tomsquest.com/blog/2014/01/intro-java-agent-and-bytecode-manipulation/)

Comment: @VinceEmigh Acknowledged. I don't want to switch to the "blame" rhetoric, the dev team could simply say that this was not a public API anyway. But it's not a nice situation. I hope I'll pursuade the to revert the change. Bytecode manipulation is a bit too low-level, probably not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using [jarjar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/).  This is a tool that will allow you to repackage classes in a library.  You can run this against the latest version of the tool and move the SomeEnum class to a package that does not conflict with the plugins.

The [Getting Started](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/wiki/GettingStarted) doc has an example, with jaxen.jar, that looks to be relevant to your situation.

Comment: You mean, to repackage *the tool*? A very interesting idea.

Comment: Yes that is what I am suggesting.  I have never personally used it, but others have suggested this to resolve class collisions in Android (i.e. I believe there is or was some apache code embedded in core Android).

Comment: A very good idea. This will partially work. The disadvantage is that plugins compiled against the *new* version of The Tool will then fail. It's only old xor new, not both at the same time. An alias (if possible) could've allowed both to run in parallel.

Comment: But won't the failure only occur with the new library and plugins that explicitly reference the SomeEnum class?  I agree though that this is not a perfect solution.

Comment: Yes, if they do. And they will. That class is somehow stupidly central for certain tasks.

Comment: @lexicore - Have you considered simply coding up the old version of the enum (in its old package), compiling it, and injecting the resulting class file into the tool's jar?  You would then have both versions of the enum in the tool.  Very hawkish short-term solution, but it seems like it would work for plugins complied against all versions of the tool.

Comment: That won't work as plugins call some APIs of The Tool with that enum. I mean, I surely can make a copy available as `foo.SomeEnum`, but The Tool still expects `bar.SomeEnum` in its APIs. So this won't help, unfortunately. And since it's a enum, I can't even subclass it.

Comment: Sounds like there's an issue with the tool's interface segregation.